# Error Installing Tizen SDK on Mac OS X

Tags: tizen, tizen-install

I downloaded the SDK image from Tizen website and with the help of install manager, I tried to install Tizen SDK and it has failed. I am totally clueless how to resolve this. I verified the MD5 hash of the downloaded package and it's same as mentioned in the website. I also opted to install it from the web. It's also failed for the same reason.

It shows error when it install Intel haxm package. The install prompted for password and it was given properly but the installation was failed.

Here's the log

```
16:22:58 [Trace] STDERR> /Users/sarat/tizen-sdk/temp/install.sh: line 45: /Users/sarat/tmp/sysctl.conf: Permission denied
16:22:58 [Trace] Command exit code => 1
16:22:58 [Error] Exit code => 1
16:22:58 [Error] Fail to execute install script.
16:22:58 [Error] Fatal error occurred while installing the Tizen SDK.
16:22:58 [Excep] org.tizen.installmanager.core.IMFatalException: Fatal error occurred while installing the Tizen SDK.
org.tizen.installmanager.core.IMFatalException: Fatal error occurred while installing the Tizen SDK.
    at org.tizen.installmanager.core.Installer.install(Installer.java:123)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.core.InstallManager.install(InstallManager.java:685)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.core.InstallManager.install(InstallManager.java:804)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.ViewController.install(ViewController.java:325)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.InstallingPage.installProcess(InstallingPage.java:222)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.InstallingPage$InstallThread.run(InstallingPage.java:196)
16:22:58 [Error] Fatal error occurred while installing the Tizen SDK.
16:22:58 [Error] internal error occurred
16:22:58 [Excep] org.tizen.installmanager.core.IMFatalException: Fatal error occurred while installing the Tizen SDK.
org.tizen.installmanager.core.IMFatalException: Fatal error occurred while installing the Tizen SDK.
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.ViewController.install(ViewController.java:334)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.InstallingPage.installProcess(InstallingPage.java:222)
    at org.tizen.installmanager.ui.page.InstallingPage$InstallThread.run(InstallingPage.java:196)
16:22:58 [Trace] Set installation success: false
16:22:58 [Trace] </Users/sarat/tizen-sdk/sdk.info> exists already. it will be removed.
16:22:58 [Trace] Success to delete file. => /Users/sarat/tizen-sdk/sdk.info
16:22:58 [Trace] Success to create file. => /Users/sarat/tizen-sdk/sdk.info
16:22:58 [Trace] finish install thread
16:22:58 [Trace] (un)installation failed
```

[image: Installing package]

and fails

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I got the same error because my '~/tmp' file was owned by root. This stopped me installing the emulator.

After typing

```
chown -R $USER ~/tmp
```

into a terminal and re running the installer, it was successful

https://developer.tizen.org/forums/sdk-ide/sdk-installation-failed-mac

Comment: you should probably add "sudo". didn't solve the problem for me. thanks anyway